# Unable to parameterize python requests json strucrture

Tags: json, python-2.7, python-requests

I am trying to use python `request` module to send value to a REST API -

The code looks like -

```
headers={'content-type':'application/json', 'accept': 'application/json'}
url = 'url'
var1 = 'val'

data1 = 
{
"data":{
"parameter":var1
       }
}

r = requests.post(url, data = json.dumps(data1), headers=headers)
print r.text
```

This is code is failing with rc=500. The error suggests that `var1` is not identified properly. Can someone guide me how do we send `var1` to the json structure?

Comment: I put data1 on one line, and the client seems to work fine going to my own POST service. The syntax of the request appears to be correct, but you need to determine why the service is rejecting it.

Comment: Thanks for your response ! Indeed I figured out that the syntax is correct. It was the problem on the side of REST API